# Get value from array if not out of bounds

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm looking for the most elegant solution to get values from an `object[]` when the requested index is not out of bounds.

My current solution is as follows:

```
    public object GetNamedParametersFrom(GenericObject genericObject)
    {
        string nameFromListOne = String.Empty;
        string nameFromListTwo = String.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < genericObject.ListOfThings.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    nameFromListOne = genericObject.ListOfThings[i].Name;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    nameFromListTwo = genericObject.ListOfThings[i].Name;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return new {
           nameFromListOne,
           nameFromListTwo
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there many such variables like resourceSix and so on?

Comment: Right now the project is only asking for these two - However I would like to cater for that if possible.

Comment: The code does not compile - `object` is a reserved keyword and if `object.Resources` is an `object[]`, there is no `Name` property. Might as well provide the requried casts, perhaps it influences what is the "most elegant solution"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Why not use the built-in [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.110).aspx) method from Linq?

```
string[] names =
    { "Hartono, Tommy", "Adams, Terry", "Andersen, Henriette Thaulow",
        "Hedlund, Magnus", "Ito, Shu" };

int index = 20;

string name = names.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
```

Comment: It is best answer! ElementAtOrDefault checks enumerable for IList to avoid performance problems and it is built-in as Rasmus said.

Comment: The most up to date and best answer.

Comment: Marked as the answer for relevance.

Comment: Z is Z genius programmaa

Answer (score 6):

Why not use an `Array`?

```
public object GetNamedParametersFrom(GenericObject genericObject)
{
    string[] namesFromLists = new string[genericObject.ListOfThings.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < genericObject.ListOfThings.Count; i++)
    {
        namesFromLists[i] = genericObject.ListOfThings[i].Name;
    }

    return namesFromLists; //As you are returning an `object`, you can return `resources` array directly from this method
}
```

Comment: This still leads back to the origional issue - I need to assign them to primitive type properties, so I'm just making an array from a list to try append if there is any.

Comment: Would you like to show an example or actual code where you are using it, actually its not clear enough to me.

Answer (score 4):

How about an extension method like:

```
public static TValue GetSafe<TItem, TValue>(this IList<TItem> list, 
    int index, Func<TItem, TValue> selector, TValue defaultValue)
{
  // other checks omitted
  if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)
  {
    return defaultValue;
  }
  return selector(list[index]);
}
```

You can use this then like:

```
var items = new[] {"Hello", "World", "!"};

var value0 = items.GetSafe(0, s => s.Length, 0);
var value1 = items.GetSafe(1, s => s.Length, 0);
var value2 = items.GetSafe(2, s => s.Length, 0);
var value3 = items.GetSafe(3, s => s.Length, 0);
```

The last line won't throw an error and `value3` will be set to `0` (the `defaultValue`).

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Rasmus, using LINQ's [ElementAtOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ElementAtOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Int32_) is your best bet. Add some NULL checks if you can't guarantee the number of elements.

```
string[] fruits = { "Apples", "Oranges", "Blueberries", "Pineapple" };

string? thirdFruit = fruits?.ElementAtOrDefault(2); // Blueberries
string? tenthFruit = fruits?.ElementAtOrDefault(9); // NULL
string? negativeFruit = fruits?.ElementAtOrDefault(-1); // NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this has an accepted answer, but a much more elegant and simple solution in my opinion is something like this:

```
var item = items.Length > n
                ? resourceProperties[n]
                : <default value you want to return if it's out of bounds>;
```

Where items is a collection

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get one `resource` by enter requested `index`

```
   if(index < object.Resources.Count){
         resource = object.Resources[index].Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extension method

```
public T TryGetElement<T>(this T[] array, int index, T defaultElement) {
  if ( index < array.Length ) {
    return array[index];
  }
  return defaultElement;
}
```

Use it like this

```
// Select name to a string[]
var names = @object.Resources.Select(i => i.Name).ToArray();

resourceOne = names.TryGetElement(0, null);
resourceTwo = names.TryGetElement(1, null);
```

Comment: What if `names` only has 1 ?

Comment: @SemiDemented `names` is an array, of course it can have 0 to n items

Comment: I don't think you get what I mean. If you have only 1 item, `names[1]` witll throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Eric's method is nice; but should do a full bounds check on the array:

```
public T ElementOrDefault<T>(this T[] array, int index, T defaultElement) {
  if ( index < array.GetLowerBound(0) || index > array.GetUpperBound(0) ) {
    return defaultElement;
  }
  return array[index];
}
```

Comment: Also I might add, there is good reason for a method like this. In unit tests you may want to check that an expected array is the same as an actual array. This method makes that easy without too much safety checking code.