# C# - Facing error in Collection model - Null Handling

Tags: c#, .net

I have method as shown below this method called inside the for loop in C# code, this works fine in case if the ProductLevelRecords has the records in that specified Index but it throws error if there are no records in the given Index, please let me know how to fix this error

```
private static bool HasRecords(CardFileModel CardFileModel, int index)
{
    if (CardFileModel?.ProductLevelRecords[index] != null) [this line gives error if no records in that index level]
    { 
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CardFileModel?.ProductLevelRecords[index]?.OrderNumber.Trim());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Exception message - "There is no row at position 1."

I am getting exception here - CardFileModel?.ProductLevelRecords[index]-  that's true there are no rows assigned in index position 1 in this collection.
so how to avoid this error message - Can you please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value from array if not out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341810/get-value-from-array-if-not-out-of-bounds)

Comment: Its not a duplicate question, the above link is about LIST mine is not list object - its Class model

Comment: _"the above link is about LIST mine is not list object"_ -- a good example of why when you are posting a question you should always make sure to provide a proper [mcve]. That said, there are other posts of which your question _is_ a duplicate. I've updated the duplicate targets to be appropriate for your database-oriented scenario. (though, frankly, the previous duplicate would still be useful to someone who looked at the basic techniques used, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30342302).

Comment: you may need to handle index out of range exception by checking `length` before reading data `if (index < CardFileModel.ProductLevelRecords.Length)`

Comment: Thank you, I don't see the Length/Count property in my class -

Comment: can also share `CardFileModel` class model in you question.

Comment: public sealed class CardFileModel { public ProductLevelTwoDataTable ProductLevelRecords { get; set; } public ProductLevelThreeDataTable ProductLevelRecords { get; set; } }

Comment: public class ProductLevelDataTable : DataTable { public ProductLevelDataTable() { this.TableName = "XYZ"; this.Columns.Add("ProductLevelId", typeof(int)); this.PrimaryKey = new[] { this.Columns["ProductLevelId"] }; this.Columns.Add("ProductIdentifier", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 1; this.Columns.Add("ProductType", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 2; this.Columns.Add("ProductSequenceNumber", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 3; } }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can replace `[index]` with `.ElementAtOrDefault(index)`.

**EDIT:**

Apparently, ProductLevelRecords is not IEnumerable.
I know it has an indexer though and assume it has a `Length` property.

Try the following code:

```
if (CardFileModel == null || index >= CardFileModel.ProductLevelRecords.Length)
    return false;
```

It may be called Count.

Try the following code:

```
if (CardFileModel == null || index >= CardFileModel.ProductLevelRecords.Count)
    return false;
```

**EDIT:**

If all else fails, you can use a try catch block.

```
private static bool HasRecords(CardFileModel CardFileModel, int index)
{
    try
    {
        if (CardFileModel?.ProductLevelRecords[index] != null)
        { 
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CardFileModel?.ProductLevelRecords[index]?.OrderNumber.Trim());
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the quick response, I tried the blow line - CardFileModel?.ProductLevelRecords.ElementAtOrDefault(index) Its giving an error - does not contain a definition for 'ElementAtOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'ElementAtOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'ProductLevelRecords' could be found

Comment: Basically CardFileModel is not a List/IEnumerable , that's why I am not getting that property, can you suggest me what is other way i can verify

Comment: I am not seeing "Length" option in my CardFileModel.ProductLevelRecords - Its giving error - Does not contain definition of Length. - Can you please suggest me

Comment: @Manas, what type is `CardFileModel`?

Comment: Thank you for spending time with me - Even Count() method also not available = CardFileModel.ProductLevelRecords.Count()

Comment: @Manas, Count will probably be a property.

Comment: public sealed class CardFileModel
    {
        public ProductLevelTwoDataTable ProductLevelRecords { get; set; }
        public ProductLevelThreeDataTable ProductLevelRecords { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public class ProductLevelDataTable : DataTable
    {
      public ProductLevelDataTable()
        {
            this.TableName = "XYZ";
            this.Columns.Add("ProductLevelId", typeof(int));
            this.PrimaryKey = new[] { this.Columns["ProductLevelId"] };
            this.Columns.Add("ProductIdentifier", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 1;
            this.Columns.Add("ProductType", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 2;
            this.Columns.Add("ProductSequenceNumber", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 3;
  }
    }

Comment: @Manas, I believe you can do `CardFileModel?.ProductLevelRecords.Rows.ElementAtOrDefault(index)`

Comment: actually still no luck - I am getting error 'DataRowcollection doesn't not contain definition of ElementAtOrDefault'

Comment: @Manas, Try `if (CardFileModel == null || index >= CardFileModel.ProductLevelRecords.Rows.Count) return false;`